# Sum Of Arrays Using .where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Probably a super easy solution, but trying to figure out how to find the sum of the 'amount' integer columns that belong to:

```
@milestones = Milestone.where(:buyer_id => current_user.id).where(:status => 'Paid')
```

I tried `<%= @milestones.amount.inject(:+) %>` in the view, didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, it didn't work. There's no `amount` on array of `Milestone`s. Try this:

```
@milestones.map(&:amount).inject(:+)
```

Answer (score 5):

Given:

```
@milestones = Milestone.where( :buyer_id => current_user.id ).
                        where( :status   => 'Paid' )
```

Then...

```
<%= @milestones.sum :amount %>
```

Or just:

```
@milestones_sum = Milestone.where( :buyer_id => current_user.id,
                                   :status   => 'Paid'
                                 ).
                            sum( :amount )
```

And...

```
<%= @milestones_sum %>
```

Comment: Does the sum method wind up using SQL to create the sum on the database end? If so, then that's probably the best approach since it will return less data and allow the database to do the work at a lower level.

Comment: Yes, sum is part of [ActiveRecord::Calculations](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 2):

`@milestones` does not have an `amount` method because it's not a `Milestone`— it's an `ActiveRecord::Relation` or an `Array`.

You can try `@milestones.map(&:amount).inject(:+)`, to collect and sum all of the amount numbers in the Rails application.

Or you can use `@milestones.sum(:amount)` to have ActiveRecord perform the calculation in the database for you, which could be much faster / efficient. Other calculations are also available in [ActiveRecord::Calculations::ClassMethods](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html).